# how to remove namespace from an existing xml subtree in oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm facing an issue with removing namespace from existing xml subtree.

For Example: I have a table with 1 field - data type xmltype. One entry is holding this xml:

```
<Item xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Box>Blaff</Box>
  <Door>Steal</Door>
  <Chair>Wood</Chair>
</Item>
```

I would like to remove the namespace - i.e.:

```
<Item>
  <Box>Black-box</Box>
  <Door>Steal</Door>
  <Chair>Wood</Chair>
</Item>
```

Do you have any suggestions? - I tried using the `UPDATE()` function with no luck.
Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to transform it to a clob, then replace the namespace string and transform it back to xml:

```
            with xtab as (
            select xmltype('<Item xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <Box>Blaff</Box>
              <Door>Steal</Door>
              <Chair>Wood</Chair>
            </Item>') my_xml from dual)
            select xmltype(replace(xmltype.getclobval(my_xml), 
                          ' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"', ''))  clo
            from xtab;
```