REGEXP_COUNT buffer too small in Oracle SQL
I have the following SQL:
            with q1 ( Tdata,Key) AS (
    SELECT  (XMLtype(pint.transportdata, nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')))
    , PINT.PAYMENTINTERCHANGEKEY
  from bph_owner.paymentinterchange pint
  where         PINT.TRANSPORTTIME >= to_date('2024-01-11 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:Ss')
       AND  PINT.TRANSPORTTIME < to_date('2024-04-12 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:Ss')
       AND  LENGTH(pint.transportdata)>0
       AND PINT.FILEFORMAT like 'pain%'
  )
    SELECT  C1.column_value , q1.Key from q1,
  XMLTABLE(
     '//*'
           PASSING q1.Tdata
              )   C1
  --where regexp_count( C1.column_value,'<') < 2
      ;

Which works - sample output :



COLUMN_VALUE




<Id xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"><PrvtId><Othr><Id>IE57ZZZ05327119</Id><SchmeNm><Prtry>SEPA</Prtry></SchmeNm>/Othr></PrvtId></Id>


<PrvtId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"><Othr><Id>IE57ZZZ05327119</Id><SchmeNm><Prtry>SEPA</Prtry></SchmeNm>/Othr>/PrvtId>


<Othr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"><Id>IE57ZZZ05327119</Id><SchmeNm><Prtry>SEPA</Prtry></SchmeNm></Othr>


<Id xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02">IE57ZZZ05327119</Id>


<SchmeNm xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"><Prtry>SEPA</Prtry></SchmeNm>


<Prtry xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02">SEPA</Prtry>



But If I try to use the REGEXP_COUNT it gives :
ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small

If I cut the predicate down to a smaller date range I get it to work :



COLUMN_VALUE




<FinInstnId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"/>



Any idea how I can get this to work with a larger date range?

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data to allow us to replicate the problem. (We cannot work out how to get your desired output if we don't know what we are starting with.)

Your filter:
where regexp_count( C1.column_value,'<') < 2

Appears to be matching leaf elements of the XML that contain no text.
If that is the logic that you are after then don't use a regular expression; instead, search for those conditions directly in the XPath expression when you parse the XML.

//*[not(*)] will find elements with no children;
//*[not(text())] will find elements with no text; and
you can combine them both to //*[not(*)][not(text())]

Like this:
SELECT  C1.column_value,
        p.paymentinterchangekey AS Key
FROM    bph_owner.paymentinterchange p
        CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
          '//*[not(*)][not(text())]'
           PASSING XMLtype(p.transportdata)
        ) C1
WHERE   p.TRANSPORTTIME >= DATE '2024-01-11'
AND     p.TRANSPORTTIME <  DATE '2024-04-12'
AND     LENGTH(p.transportdata)>0
AND     p.FILEFORMAT like 'pain%';

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE paymentinterchange (
  transportdata,
  paymentinterchangekey,
  transporttime,
  fileformat
) AS
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '<Id xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"><PrvtId><Othr><Id>IE57ZZZ05327119</Id><SchmeNm><Prtry>SEPA</Prtry></SchmeNm></Othr></PrvtId></Id>',
       1,
       DATE '2024-01-11',
       'paint'
FROM   DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '<FinInstnId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"/>',
       2,
       DATE '2024-01-11',
       'paint'
FROM   DUAL;

Outputs:



COLUMN_VALUE
KEY




<FinInstnId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"/>
2



fiddle

Many thanks - I have it working though I needed to slightly amend :
PASSING XMLtype(p.transportdata, nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'))
Much appreciated !

being cheeky here, is there a way the output can have the namespace removed ?
Thanks again

@Peterwarren you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/24308225/1509264 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/29354318/1509264 - if they don't answer your question then you should probably ask a new question

C1.column_value is (implicitly) an XMLType. You are passing that into regexp_count(), which expects a character value. That means your XMLType is implicitly converted, and by default that will use getstringval(). Once you get a column_value that is more than 4000 bytes (or maybe 32k depending on your version/settings) you'll see this error. That's why it sometimes works - with different date ranges you just happen to avoid the longer values.
To pass it in as a CLOB instead, explicitly convert it:
regexp_count( C1.column_value.getclobval(),'<')

But don't do this anyway; do what @MT0 said...

Many thanks - I did try that before but for some reason it doesn't like the
SELECT  C1.column_value , q1.Key from q1,
XMLTABLE(
'//*'
PASSING q1.Tdata
)   C1
where regexp_count( C1.column_value.getclobval(),'<')
;
I get :
[Error] Execution (92: 54): ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
but the @MT0 suggestions is working.
Thanks for your time and help.

@Peterwarren - you seem to have lost the < 2 part...
